# how to fetch data from two different models in single api call in django rest frame work? is it possibel if yes then how?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am having trouble getting data of two models from a single view in Django rest framework. Here is what I have done so far, but I am not sure how can I get the data from two models using single view.

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('users/<int:id>/', GenericAPIView.as_view()),
    path('users/', GenericAPIView.as_view()),

]
```

```
# User Serializer
class userSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'


# usersdata serializer

class userdataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserData
        fields = '__all__'
```

this is my views.py

```
class GenericAPIView(generics.GenericAPIView, mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                     mixins.UpdateModelMixin):
    serializer_class = userdataSerializer, userSerializer
    queryset = UserData.objects.all()

    lookup_field = 'id'



    def get(self, request, id=None):
        if id:
            return self.retrieve(request)
        else:
            return self.list(request)

    def post(self, request):

        return self.create(request)

    def put(self, request, id=None):
        return self.update(request, id)
```

Answer (score 2):

I am clearing https://stackoverflow.com/users/8661327/eternal 's answer (can't comment, not enough reputation). I guess you'd want to use [Nested Relationships](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships) concept. From the docs:

```py
class TrackSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Track
        fields = ['order', 'title', 'duration']

class AlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tracks = TrackSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Album
        fields = ['album_name', 'artist', 'tracks']
```

If you see the output of an Album, it will show up like following:

```
{
    'album_name': 'The Grey Album',
    'artist': 'Danger Mouse',
    'tracks': [
        {'order': 1, 'title': 'Public Service Announcement', 'duration': 245},
        {'order': 2, 'title': 'What More Can I Say', 'duration': 264},
        {'order': 3, 'title': 'Encore', 'duration': 159},
        ...
    ],
}
```

In your case, modify `serializers.py` to look like this:

```py
# User Serializer
class userSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_data = userdataSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'
        fields += ["user_data"]


# usersdata serializer

class userdataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserData
        fields = '__all__'
```

This way, your `User` contains data from `UserData` model too.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify one of the serializers to include another one.

```
class userSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_data = userdataSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('field1', 'field2', 'user_data', ...)
```

Comment: I am not sure how to do it exactly